# MNIST dataset overfitting

Tags: pytorch, mnist, overfitting-underfitting

[image: This is the plot that i am getting]I am working with the MNIST dataset and I have created the following network. I want to overfit the training data and I think I am doing that here. My training loss is lower than my validation loss. This is the code that I have come up with. Please look at it and let me know if I am overfitting the training data, if I am not then how do I go about it?

```
 class NN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.layers = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Flatten(),
    nn.Linear(784,4096),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(4096,2048),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(2048,1024),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(1024,512),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(512,256),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(256,128),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(128,64),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(64,32),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(32,16),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(16,10))
def forward(self,x):
    return self.layers(x)
def accuracy_and_loss(model, loss_function, dataloader):
    total_correct = 0
    total_loss = 0
    total_examples = 0
    n_batches = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in testloader:
            images, labels = data
            outputs = model(images)
            batch_loss = loss_function(outputs,labels)
            n_batches += 1
            total_loss += batch_loss.item()
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
            total_examples += labels.size(0)
            total_correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
    accuracy = total_correct / total_examples
    mean_loss = total_loss / n_batches
    return (accuracy, mean_loss)
def define_and_train(model,dataset_training, dataset_test):
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader( small_trainset, batch_size=500, shuffle=True)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader( dataset_test, batch_size=500, shuffle=True)
values = [1e-8,1e-7,1e-6,1e-5]
model = NN()
for params in values:
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay = 1e-7)
    train_acc = []
    val_acc = []
    train_loss = []
    val_loss = []
    for epoch in range(100):
    
        total_loss = 0
        total_correct = 0
        total_examples = 0
        n_mini_batches = 0
    
        for i,mini_batch in enumerate(trainloader,0):
        
            images,labels = mini_batch
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = loss_function(outputs,labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            n_mini_batches += 1
            total_loss += loss.item()
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
            total_examples += labels.size(0)
            total_correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        
        epoch_training_accuracy = total_correct / total_examples
        epoch_training_loss = total_loss / n_mini_batches
        epoch_val_accuracy, epoch_val_loss = accuracy_and_loss( model, loss_function, testloader )

        print('Params %f Epoch %d loss: %.3f acc: %.3f val_loss: %.3f val_acc: %.3f'
              %(params, epoch+1, epoch_training_loss, epoch_training_accuracy, epoch_val_loss, epoch_val_accuracy))
    
        train_loss.append( epoch_training_loss )
        train_acc.append( epoch_training_accuracy )
        val_loss.append( epoch_val_loss )
        val_acc.append( epoch_val_accuracy )

    history = { 'train_loss': train_loss, 
                'train_acc': train_acc, 
                'val_loss': val_loss,
                'val_acc': val_acc }
    return ( history, model ) 
history1, net1 = define_and_train(model,dataset_training,dataset_test)
```

I am trying to overfit the training data so that later i can apply regularization and then reduce the overfitting which will give me a better understanding of the process

Comment: Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although I won't attempt to provide a rigorous definition, the term "overfit" typically means that the training loss continues to decrease whereas the validation loss stays stagnant at a position higher than the training loss, or continues to increase with more iterations.

Therefore, it is difficult to know whether your network is overfitting solely based on your code alone. Since dense, fully-connected networks tend to overfit easily in the absence of dropout layers or other regularizers, my hunch would be that your network is indeed overfitting according to your intention. However, we would have to see your tensorboard logs or loss plot to determine whether the model is overfitting.

If you want to overfit your network to the dataset, I suggest that you construct a much larger model with more hidden layers. Overfitting occurs when the dataset is "too easy" for the model and it starts to remember the training set itself without learning generalizable patterns that can be applied to the validation set.

Comment: i have added the plot that i am getting. Looking at it is my model overfitting?

Comment: Also, when i am trying to reduce overfitting, i am using weight_decay in my optimizer. I do not find any difference in the training and validation loss. Why is that so?

Comment: Not quite, since the validation loss is still decreasing as far as I can tell. See here: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/overfitting. You want the validation loss to have an inflection point, i.e., stop decreasing and shoot upwards.

Comment: As for the weight decay: when you say you see no difference, have you actually checked that they are the same to the decimal points? I would suspect the values would be different, although the general trend could be very similar. The dataset and model here are simple, and it's unlikely weight decay will make it or break it.

Comment: Two options. (1) Train your model for longer. (2) As stated in my answer, construct a larger model with more layers (more `nn.Linear`) or more hidden units (`nn.Linear(784, 512)` instead of `nn.Linear(784, 64)`). Note that you would have to adjust the next layers accordingly.

Comment: Yes, more epochs. `nn.Linear(784, X)` would be followed by `nn.Linear(X, Y)`, then `nn.Linear(Y, Z)`. `Z` would be 10 at some point.

Comment: Yes. I would suggest you follow the PyTorch tutorial to understand the innerworkings of the hidden layers, etc. Also, if you have follow up questions, please consider opening a new thread and marking this answer as accepted if you found it helpful. Thanks!

Comment: How many epochs is this?

Comment: It's working now. I have overfit the data and using regularization the loss is decreasing as well. But I am using individual values each time. How do I loop through the values? I have tried for a loop. Can you please check where I am going wrong?

Comment: I have updated the code as well

Comment: The for loop that i have used is only taking the first value or the last value. It is not looping through all the values.